# Is it possible to create a password-protected ZIP file with Flutter / Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, passwords, zip, protected

I would like to create a ZIP file that is protected with a password.

Has anyone done this before and can you give me a few tips? I couldn't find a reasonable package on pub.dev.

Comment: use `ZipEncoder`

Comment: @pskink Unfortunately, I can't find anything about this at Dart.dev. There is also no package under pub.dev with this name. Can you please give me a little more details?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/index.html - there is a search box on the top right corner

Comment: oops, bad news: seems that `ZipDecoder` supports [passwords](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/archive_io/ZipDecoder/decodeBytes.html), while `ZipEncoder` does not ;-(

Comment: this plugin seems to do the trick. I haven't tested it so I'll just add it as comment: https://github.com/jlcool/flutter_zip_archive/blob/master/lib/flutter_zip_archive.dart

Comment: This is not supported by `archive`, as per https://github.com/brendan-duncan/archive/issues/95. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69072762/7365866 is a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

Plugin `archive`

https://pub.dev/packages/archive

Use this plugin you can do like this:

```
 final archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBytes(
      _file,
      verify: true,
      password: "your_password", )
```

Comment: No, i don't want to open or read a zip file. I want to CREATE an zip file with a password.  As I understood it I have decodeBytes for opening / reading an already existing ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this unpublished plugin [flutter_zip_archive](https://github.com/jlcool/flutter_zip_archive) just download the code and use it. For better future development add the method channels from the repo to your app with the files included in the lib folder.
This package supports zipping and unzipping the files with passwords. It also provides the privilege of adding the destination where the zip file should be stored.
PS. To encrypt a file you'll need a file available locally before zipping.