# How to add password lock to a zip file or any file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, zip, flutter-dependencies, password-encryption

How to add password lock to a zip file or any file in flutter?

I am using ZipFileEncoder for creating a zip file, but this does not allow to add password lock to it. How can I lock this file with password protection?

Is there any other way instead of using native platform specific code?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jlcool/flutter_zip_archive didn't test - but it looks like you can set a passcode here.

Found from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69083469/5812524